# Creating real-time monitor window of an application

Tags: winapi, user-interface, screenshot, capture

I want to create a window that can display the current content of an application, say Powerpoint or Adobe Reader.

When I run my application, I would first select which of the currently running application I need to monitor in realtime. Once done, I need to get the current content of the selected application and display it. Since my application is going to be realtime, it will need to  capture the contents of the selected application as and when they change (with minimal lag), and then display it.

As I understand, this broadly comprise of the following steps:
1. Selecting an application that I want to monitor
2. Get 'notification' when the content of that applicaion (client area) has changed
3. Capture the new content and display it

The steps [1] and [3] are quite easy and I find several methods here to perform them. However, for the stage [2] I am still clueless. Can anybody throw some light on how to acheive this?

Cheers.

Comment: You'd think this got much easier in Windows Vista/7 with DWM and Aero Peek, but I'm not aware of any APIs for taking advantage of the DWM render.

Comment: A cursory glance on DWM shows that it's working differs with Win7/Vista and also with WDDM version. I will probably not take this approach since would like to support all using the same codebase, if that's acheiveable. Also didn't find any mention of XP in it's support list.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com), which does exactly what you are trying to do (it has a single window mode as well as full-screen).  It has no less than four ways to accomplish your step #2.

Answer (score 1):

The one obvious approach I can think of is to periodically take snapshots of the app's window and compare it to the previous one for changes.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this before. I feel there should be better ways to handle this, polling is really crude and fall back option when nothing else exist/works.